# What does this tip mean?

Tags: c

I need to write such a program:

> Write a program that will fill an array with 30 elements of type int randomly selected from range 0 to 10. Print the array content on the screen. Then count and print out how many times each value appears in the array (tip: histogram).

Can somebody explain what this tip means?

Comment: An histogram? Search on the web!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram

Comment: An histogram is a specific data visualization technique that let's you efficiently show an indicator's value for a discrete and finite set of values (here the indicator is the number of appearances and your discrete set of values are integers ranging from 0 to 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Histogram is a representation, you can look it up online. Simply put in your, showing an item and its frequency(no:of occurrences) in a pictorial form. Check this image[image]

Number column has the items that are present in your array, and count column has number of times each of them occur in your array(frequency). Frequency adds up to your array size - 30. Representing an item with its frequency is a histogram. And the graph is a pictorial representation.

The **tip** tells you what printing representation(number and its count) is.